# How to check if a DataFrame was already cached/persisted before?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For spark's RDD object this is quite trivial as it exposes a getStorageLevel method, but DF does not seem to expose anything similar. anyone?

Comment: If a DataFrame is cached, a new .cache or .persist won't bring any overhead. Why do you need to know if it's cached?

Comment: why not `df.rdd.getStorageLevel` ? why `df.getStorageLevel` or some other method like is cache is needed? is there any specific requirement for this? yes you are right I went through code but haven't found any such method

Comment: @DenieldePaula Why is it difficult to understand the value of this inquiry?  Calling `.cache()` *again* does not tell you :  ( a ) was it already cached (or did something go wrong) . ( b ) did it get cached *this* time (or did something go wrong..).   This is a good question.

Answer (score 5):

You can check weather a DataFrame is cached or not using `Catalog (org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Catalog)` which comes in Spark 2.

Code example :

```scala
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName("example")
      .getOrCreate()

    val df = sparkSession.read.csv("src/main/resources/sales.csv")
    df.createTempView("sales")

    //interacting with catalog

    val catalog = sparkSession.catalog

    //print the databases

    catalog.listDatabases().select("name").show()

    // print all the tables

    catalog.listTables().select("name").show()

    // is cached
    println(catalog.isCached("sales"))
    df.cache()
    println(catalog.isCached("sales"))
```

Using the above code you can **list all the tables** and check weather a table is **cached** or not.

You can check the working code example [here](https://github.com/engineerpawan/spark-learning/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/spark/two/updates/CatalogExample.scala#L38)